# PHP How to Add a variable to an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make a variable with the category number (14 in the example) add pass it to the get_posts array. I have created a custom field to pass the category ID.

```
<?php
$field = the_field('category_num');
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 200, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'category' => $field);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
```

This is using Wordpress.

The problem is that this not working, basically: inside $args , **'category' => $field);** is not showing the number ID of the category.

is this the correct syntax? can somebody please point out what im doing wrong?

Comment: Could you clearly state, in the body of your question, what your question is?

Comment: sorry I was updating the question, now it is updated. please dont downvote.

Comment: No, problem. And yes, the syntax of your array is correct. Please also specify 'this is not working'. What isn't?

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something along the lines of Wordpress Documented Patterns. The code below might be worth considering:

```
    <?php

        global $post;  // READY THE $post FOR USE IN THE setup_postdata() FUNCTION

        $field      = the_field('category_num');
        $args       = array( 'numberposts' => 200, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'category' => $field); // NOTICE THE USE OF numberposts RATHER THAN posts_per_page
        $postsList  = get_posts( $args );

        foreach ( $postsList as $post ){
            setup_postdata( $post );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `the_field('category_num')` will work - it's not a default Wordpress function.

Get the post id for the post you want the category of and store it in $post_ID. Then you can use:

```
$postcat = get_the_category($post_ID);
$field = $postcat['cat_ID'];
```

then your $args should work.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/